# SQLiteLog( 8646): (1) table tempsettings has no column named user

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm learning how to upgrade databases in an flutter application, apears to be very simple, but I'm getting this error executing an INSERT:

> E/SQLiteLog( 9107): (1) table tempsettings has no column named user
>   I/flutter ( 9107): DatabaseException(table tempsettings has no column
>   named user (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   tempsettings('id', 'user', 'company', 'url') SELECT 'id', 'user',
>   'company', 'url' FROM settings) E/SQLiteLog( 9107): (1) no such
>   column: user I/flutter ( 9107): DatabaseException(no such column: user
>   (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO settings('id',
>   'user', 'company', 'url', 'theme') SELECT id, user, company, url, 1
>   FROM tempsettings)

```
    await db
        .execute("CREATE TABLE tempsettings("
            "'id' INTEGER "
            "'user' TEXT,"
            "'company' TEXT,"
            "'url' TEXT)")
        .catchError((error) => print(error.toString()));
    await db.execute(
        "INSERT INTO tempsettings('id', 'user', 'company', 'url') SELECT 'id', 'user', 'company', 'url' FROM settings")
        .catchError((error) => print(error.toString()));
```

Does anyone could help me how to do this INSERT?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove the single quotes around the table names ie `await 
        db.execute("""CREATE TABLE tempsettings(
            id INTEGER, 
            user TEXT,
            company TEXT,
            url TEXT)""")` Also make sure you didn't create a table first then edit the code by adding new column, you need to uninstall the app first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the id column creation

```
await db.execute("CREATE TABLE tempsettings("
            "id INTEGER ", //this comma was missing
            "user TEXT,"
            "company TEXT,"
            "url TEXT)")
        .catchError((error) => print(error.toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks, after this I could see that today it's not a good day for me! ehuehuehueuehu